# Javascript code works when run without server, but does not work (partially) when run on server?

Tags: html, http, server

I have a Javascript code which convert numeral to its number name (e.g 120 to One Hundred and Twenty).

When I open the webpage and try to use it locally, it works as expected (Screenshots below).

but when I run it on any server (http server such as Wamp or mangoose or on github.io), the result is not as expected. It inserts the word "undefined" in between.

[Screenshot when running locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtvNw.png)

You can see the code at https://github.com/saurabhshri/pathology

The javascript code is located in script.js, while is invoked in index.html

EDIT1: Apparently I can not post more than one link. So I am only attaching my github link, where you can see the whole code and try it yourself.

EDIT2 : Here's the js code responsible for conversion :

```js
 var a = ['','one ','two ','three ','four ', 'five ','six ','seven ','eight ','nine ','ten ','eleven ','twelve ','thirteen ','fourteen ','fifteen ','sixteen ','seventeen ','eighteen ','nineteen '];
var b = ['', '', 'twenty','thirty','forty','fifty', 'sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety'];

function inWords (num) {
    if ((num = num.toString()).length > 9) return 'overflow';
    n = ('000000000' + num).substr(-9).match(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{1})(\d{2})$/);
    if (!n) return; var str = '';
    str += (n[1] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[1])] || b[n[1][0]] + ' ' + a[n[1][1]]) + 'crore ' : '';
    str += (n[2] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[2])] || b[n[2][0]] + ' ' + a[n[2][1]]) + 'lakh ' : '';
    str += (n[3] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[3])] || b[n[3][0]] + ' ' + a[n[3][1]]) + 'thousand ' : '';
    str += (n[4] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[4])] || b[n[4][0]] + ' ' + a[n[4][1]]) + 'hundred ' : '';
    str += (n[5] != 0) ? ((str != '') ? 'and ' : '') + (a[Number(n[5])] || b[n[5][0]] + ' ' + a[n[5][1]]) + 'only ' : '';
    return str;
}
```

Here's when the above js code is called (last line) :

```js
/* Update Invoice
/* ========================================================================== */

function updateInvoice() {
 var total = 0;
 var cells, price, total, a, i;

 // update inventory cells
 // ======================

 for (var a = document.querySelectorAll('table.inventory tbody tr'), i = 0; a[i]; ++i) {
  // get inventory row cells
  cells = a[i].querySelectorAll('span:last-child');

  // set price as cell[2] * cell[3]
  price = parseFloatHTML(cells[2]);// * parseFloatHTML(cells[3]);

  // add price to total
  total += price;

  // set row total
  cells[4].innerHTML = price;
 }

 // update balance cells
 // ====================

 // get balance cells
 cells = document.querySelectorAll('table.balance td:last-child span:last-child');

 // set total
 cells[0].innerHTML = total;

 // set balance and meta balance
 cells[2].innerHTML = document.querySelector('table.meta tr:last-child td:last-child span:last-child').innerHTML = parsePrice(total - parseFloatHTML(cells[1]));

 // update prefix formatting
 // ========================

 var prefix = document.querySelector('#prefix').innerHTML;
 for (a = document.querySelectorAll('[data-prefix]'), i = 0; a[i]; ++i) a[i].innerHTML = prefix;

 // update price formatting
 // =======================

 for (a = document.querySelectorAll('span[data-prefix] + span'), i = 0; a[i]; ++i) if (document.activeElement != a[i]) a[i].innerHTML = parsePrice(parseFloatHTML(a[i]));

 document.getElementById("bwords").innerHTML = inWords (total); 
}
```

Here's the html code where the result is displayed :

```html
<span style="font-size: 80%;">Amount in words : Rupees </span><span style="text-transform: capitalize;" style="font-size: 80%;"id="bwords"></span>
```

EDIT3: The code works partially on the server i.e. for 250

Desired output : Two Hundred and Fifty Only

Obatined output : Twenty Undefinedhundred and fifty 5only

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) instead.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit the question rightaway.

Comment: @Quentin Added the code snippets.

Comment: Look in the browser's [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers). Do you see any error messages there? Then look in the console's network tab. Have all files loaded correctly?

Comment: @Juhana No, and yes. There's no error and all files have loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You update a local variable `a` in the function `updateInvoice()`. This is also the name of a global variable defined at line 242 in script.js, and referred to in the function `inWords()`. That's gonna be causing you problems. I would rename the global at line 242 and 254

Comment: That was the culprit! Thanks a lot! Can I also ask, how did you track it down?

Comment: I used the javascript debugger in Firebug. I stepped through the function `inWords()` line by line, and when I saw that `a` was an interger, while I could see that it was defined as a global array a few lines higher up, I knew it must have been changed somewhere.

The real lesson here is to learn one of the HTML/Javascript debuggers. Most browsers have one built in, and Firebug usually available as an extension.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me on an Apache web-server. However, I see several issues in your HTML and Javascript that could be causing problems:

1. You have two elements with the id, "invoice1". This is a likely culprit, since that's the tag your Javascript actually tries to write to.
2. At line 57, you should put a space betweens the class and the href definion. `<a style="float:right; position:absolute; right:25%;" class='no-print'href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closeNav()">`. There's something similar going on at line 142.
3. Line 89: You're closing a  that was never opened.
4. A mess of closing tags starting at line 157, beginning with a syntax error in a div tag.

Perhaps give yourself a crash course in Firebug, since that tends to find many of these problems for you.

Comment: Actually, the code writing the number name is

document.getElementById("bwords").innerHTML = inWords (total);

It is aiming for tag with id "bwords".

And that is the main problem I am having. 

PS I'll look into Firebug.